# DB2/SQL command disposed

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I have a created a class to connect with a database (SQL or DB2)

```
private DbCommand command { get; set; }
private DbConnection connection { get; set; }        

public DataTable FillTableData(String query)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (DbCommand com = command)
        {
             com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             com.CommandText = query;
             connection.Open();
             DbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
             table.Load(reader);
        }
        return table;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

In the SQL it works fine, in the DB2 i get an object disposed exception when I run it a seccond time. I don't see why 'command' must be disposed.
And how to to avoid this? I can't use a new opperator because I don't know what command I created (SQLcommand or IDB2Command) at this time.

Comment: Since `command` is used in a `using` statement, it will be automatically disposed when the using scope is ended. If you don't want it disposed, just don't wrap it in a `using`.

Comment: Yes, I know that but, 'com' is in the using statement, not 'command'.

Comment: You're setting `com` to _reference the same object_ as `command`, so disposing the object referenced by `com` will have disposed the same object `command` is also referencing.

Comment: d'oh...but why don't I have the same problem with te SQL?

Comment: Good question, the SqlCommand dispose implementation doesn't really do much, but I don't have the DB2 one to look at. Maybe it actually disposes some native resource that is required for functionality.

Comment: Nitpick: DB2 is a form of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBCommand is a reference type, which means that a variable that is declared with that type contains only a pointer to some object in memory and not the object itself.

The line

```
   using(DBCommand com = command)
```

copies that pointer, leaving the **com** variable to point to the same object as the **command** variable.  The **using** statement causes that object to be disposed when the block is completed, leaving **command** pointing to a disposed object.

A disposed object should not be reused.  You are just lucky it works in SQL Server, as that should not be the case according to the .NET specifications.